# What are the traits of different types of workouts?

Tags: workout, weight-loss, strength, stamina, workout-types

To my limited knowledge - you must train differently depending on what you want to achieve. E.g. to lose weight one should do small weight lifting with lots of repetitions (also - according to my limited knowledge). What are the traits of other workout types (gain muscle strength, improve stamina, etc.). And what are the types of workouts in general?

Comment: This is a pretty general question and may be difficult to answer all the key points you're wanting to get at here... might consider asking a more specific set of questions regarding these workouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To lose weight, burn more calories
  than you eat. This can be by working
  out more or eating less.
- To gain muscle, you need to challenge
  your muscles. This is most often done
  by lifting heavy weights. You also
  need a calorie surplus in order to
  grow.
- To improve stamina do the thing that
  requires stamina longer or more
  often.

If you interpret "lose weight" as "lose fat" then there's no reason you can't do all three things at once. I don't agree that there are "types" of workouts, just different goals. Someone that just wants to lose fat might just run on a treadmill, but that doesn't mean that lifting weights wouldn't be equally (or even more) effective at that goal.